# Count the number of nodes that match a given XPath expression in XmlSpy

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlspy

I am using XmlSpy to analyze an xml file, and I want to get a quick count of the number of nodes that match a given xpath.  I know how to enter the XPathand get the list of nodes, but I am really just interested in the count.  Is it possible to get this?

I'm using XmlSpy Professional Edition version 2007 sp2, if it matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figureed it out.  I just needed to put count() around my xpath, like so:

```
count(//my/node)
```